# Were hippies in the USA "refused ambulance service" for some reason?

Tags: united-states, medicine, 1960s

In one episode of *The Simpsons*, Homer buys an old ambulance from the 1960s (I think). This is very vague in my memory, but at some point, somebody says something along the lines of:

> Many hippies were denied service in this ambulance!

Does this refer to some sort of real issue in the 1960s USA where hippies were not picked up by ambulances when hurt? If so, why would this be? Am I not understanding something obvious? Does it have something to do with them using drugs so often that they were "not taken seriously" or something? That's my only guess.

Comment: It's possible that this was due to drug abuse, real or suspected. Hippies were regarded as vagrants and criminals. In modern or any times times if ambulance crews think they're going to be beaten up, they're understandably less likely to help. And sometimes suspected drug or drink-generated incidents are treated as a lower priority than non-substance abuse related incidents. Add in a more judgmental attitude to people who dress unconventionally and it's not that surprising that this happened.

Comment: I think the underlying motivation was fear of AIDS . Much less was known about it then so due to ignorance and/or caution , I expect there were injustices.

Comment: @blacksmith37  The heyday of the hippies were the 60s and 70s.  HIV/AIDS wasn't known about until the 1980s  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HIV%2FAIDS#Discovery

Comment: @DaveGremlin - I mean, they're not wrong that there was a lot of ignorance about it in the 1960's. :-)

Comment: @blacksmith37 AIDS didn't exist as a known disease until the mid 1980s, 20 years after this supposedly happened.

Answer (score 4):

You have to realize that The Simpsons is a comedy show and, like [The Onion](https://www.theonion.com/), derives a lot of its societal comedy from extrapolating weird existing situations to extreme ends.

Back in the 1960's, before [the courts made it illegal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Rights_Act_of_1964#Title_II%E2%80%94public_accommodations), a lot of shops would refuse to serve patrons of color and anyone else they considered socially undesirable. Top of that "anyone else" list was usually "Hippies", which generally meant men with long hair, women wearing jeans, and everyone generally attired in [hippie fashion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippie#Art_and_fashion).

This attitude is documented in the 1971 song [Signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signs_(Five_Man_Electrical_Band_song)), by Five Man Electrical Band:

```
And the sign said "Long-haired freaky people
Need not apply"
So I tucked my hair up under my hat
And I went in to ask him why
He said "You look like a fine upstanding young man
I think you'll do"
So I took off my hat, I said "Imagine that
Huh! Me workin' for you!"
```

It would of course be both appalling and a violation of the common medical oaths for a professional to refuse emergency treatment to someone because of their social position. That doesn't mean it didn't happen (it certainly did with people of color). But the joke here is that an ambulance service was doing it with "hippies" too.

Comment: I recall signs in store fronts" No Shoes, No Shirts, No Service"

Comment: @justCal - Variants of those still exist, and are still legit I believe for public heath reasons. However, it shouldn't be lost on anyone that they date back to courts upholding the Civil Rights act, and disproportionally hit the poor (which in much of the South meant the local black population), and probably Hippies.

Comment: My sister had that 45rpm single!!

Comment: "before the courts made it illegal": the Civil Rights Act was not a decision of any court.  It is an act of congress.  (Also, some of the shops that refused to serve people of color did so, regardless of any personal opinion about social undesirability, because state law required it.  And even after the Civil Rights Act was passed, they retain the right to discriminate on grounds that are not protected by the act.)

Comment: @phoog - True, but local authorities regularly defied federal civil rights laws (and in fact had a long proud history of doing so going back to the start of Jim Crow), so it was repeatedly left to the courts to strike down the local laws (after someone bothered to sue over them), and to affirm that Congress did indeed have the authority to regulate a shopkeeper's behavior under their "interstate commerce" authority. So there was typically a lag of years between a federal civil rights law passing and states grudgingly actually starting to follow the law.

Comment: Pointing to a US Civil Rights law's passage as the date a civil right was fully available is an oversimplification that has the unfortunate effect of being overly generous to those who were fighting against said Civil Rights. I think its fair to say such figures deserve no such generosity.

Comment: @T.E.D. not public health reasons, though that's often used as an excuse. People believe that it's illegal "for public health reasons" to go barefoot and put up those signs stating that as the reason and even claiming "by orders of the health department". This is however wrong. The real reason is to keep out "poor people and vagrants", which would be illegal.